# Selenium Java : stale excpetion for dropdown

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am doing below steps in my test case
1.Open main page 
2.Click on one link which opens a new page(tab) 
3.Query  data  (Click on Query button. Page gets reloaded)
4.Select one drop down – “request” , fill some text data and click save 
5.Close this tab
6.From Main page , again click on the link to open this page (tab)
7.Query some data  ( Click on Query button . page gets reloaded)
8.Select one drop down  -  “response”  , fill some data and click save

I am getting error at Step-8 while selecting drop-down "Response". The same drop-down while selecting “request” worked fine. Also, I am able to select “response” if I open the page only once  (exclude steps- 3,4,5). What is happening here? I am new to selenium and tried almost every solution available for stale exception. 
The same code is working fine in my colleagues system without any issues . ( same chrome version)
I also tried by giving sleep time . Also while execution it is expanding the drop-down and I could see the “response” , but still it is not selecting the response.

These are my code snippets.  Using chrome browser.

```
************************ Testcase ******************************
public class TC_004 extends BaseClass{

    @Test
    public void TNRangeConfirm() throws InterruptedException{
        driver.get(baseURL);


        LoginUS login=new LoginUS();
        login.loginTest();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        logger.info("Starting Multiline Creation");
        PageActions icp=new PageActions();
        logger.info("Sending request");
        icp.PortReq();
        logger.info("Sending response");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        icp.PortRes();

        LogoutUS logout=new LogoutUS();
        logger.info("Logging out");
        logout.logoutTest();

    }
}
*********************************************************  


**********************Reusable Action***********************
public class PageActions extends BaseClass{
String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

MainMenuPage mmp=new MainMenuPage(driver);
ActionsPage ipdP=new ActionsPage(driver);

public void PortReq() throws InterruptedException{


    System.out.println(" Creation Multi Line : Started");
    System.out.println(" Click on Actions page");
        mmp.clickPRRADM();  // It expands the link
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        mmp.clickIPD();  // Opens the page
        Thread.sleep(60000);


        //Switch tab
        //ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
        //driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
        for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            if (!handle.equals(currentWindow)) {
                driver.switchTo().window(handle);
            }
        }

        //Read Data from Excel 
        //objExcelFile
        MngTestData mtd=new MngTestData();

        try {
            TN1 = mtd.readExcel(filePath, fileName, sheetName, "New_TN");
            TN2 = mtd.readExcel(filePath, fileName, sheetName, "TN1");
            TN3 = mtd.readExcel(filePath, fileName, sheetName, "TN2");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        System.out.println("TN : "+TN);
        ipdP.selectPortType("Request");
        ipdP.setPortNo(TN);
        ipdP.selectOwner(TN1);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        ipdP.clickQuery();
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.id("INFO_MSD_ID_0")).size() >0 ;

        if((isPresent) && (ipdP.isExist("NO RECORDS FOUND"))){ */
            System.out.println("Multi Line Creation Started");
            ipdP.selectPortAction("Request");
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            ipdP.selectNNSP(TN1);
            Thread.sleep(6000);
            ipdP.selectONSP(TN2);
            Thread.sleep(10000);

            ipdP.clickSave();
            Thread.sleep(30000);

            driver.close();
            driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
    }


public void PortRes() throws InterruptedException{

    String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

    mmp.clickPRRADM();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    mmp.clickPRRADM();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    mmp.clickIPD(); // opens page
    Thread.sleep(30000);

    //Read Data from Excel 
    //objExcelFile
    MngTestData mtd=new MngTestData();

    try {
        TN = mtd.readExcel(filePath, fileName, sheetName, "New_TN");
        onsp = mtd.readExcel(filePath, fileName, sheetName,"Old_Network");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Create Response
    System.out.println("Response Started");

    //Switch tab
    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));

    waitUntil wt= new waitUntil();

    boolean isFound=wt.waitForElement(driver, By.id("select-REC_TYPE_ID"));
        System.out.println("isFound"+isFound);

    wt.waitTillDropdownElementLoads(By.id("select-REC_TYPE_ID"), "Request");


    wt.waitTillListOfElementsVisibility(By.id("QRY_NUM_ID"));
    Thread.sleep(40000);


    ipdP.setPortNo(TN);
    wt.waitTillDropdownElementLoads(By.id("select-QRY_OWNER_ID"), owner);
    ipdP.selectOwner(owner);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    ipdP.clickQuery();
    Thread.sleep(40000);




        ipdP.selectMultiPortAction("Response");  // My code fails at this point stale excecption.
        Thread.sleep(10000);

    driver.close();
    driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);
    Thread.sleep(10000);

}

}

************************************************************************************




***********************************PageObject class ********************************

public class ActionsPage {
    WebDriver ldriver;

    public ActionsPage (WebDriver rdriver){
        ldriver=rdriver;
        PageFactory.initElements(rdriver,this);

    }

@FindBy(id="select-DETAILS_ACTION_ID")
    @CacheLookup
    WebElement selAction;


public void selectPortAction(String action){
        Select portAction = new Select(selAction);
        portAction.selectByValue(action);
    }


******************************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

I commented out @CacheLookup and it started working without any issues. But I dont know what is the reason behind this.

In PageObject class comment out @CacheLookup and this resolved my error.

```
@FindBy(id="select-DETAILS_ACTION_ID")
//@CacheLookup
WebElement selAction;
```